# Inserting dynamic user input into text() box

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to figure out how I could possibly take a user input from one text() box, and insert it into another text() box between already-inserted text and have it auto-update in real time.

*simplified example code:*

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

hello = Label(text="hello, what's your name?")
hello.grid(sticky=W)

mynameisLabel = Label(text="My name is:")
mynameisLabel.grid(row=1, sticky=W)

responseEntry = Text(width=40, height=1)
responseEntry.grid(row=1, sticky=E)

conclusionText = Text(width=40, height=5)
conclusionText.insert(END, "Ah, so your name is ")

# here is where I intend to somehow .insert() the input from responseEntry

conclusionText.insert(END, "?")
conclusionText.grid(row=2, columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I have to this is to bind the Text widget `responseEntry` to keys being released, and then have a small function so that every time this occurs, the text is re-written. This is what that looks like:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

hello = Label(text="hello, what's your name?")
hello.grid(sticky=W)

mynameisLabel = Label(text="My name is:")
mynameisLabel.grid(row=1, sticky=W)

responseEntry = Text(width=40, height=1)
responseEntry.grid(row=2, sticky=E)

conclusionText = Text(width=40, height=5)
conclusionText.insert(END, "Ah, so your name is ?")
conclusionText.grid(row=3, columnspan=2)

# This function is called whenever a key is released
def typing(event):
    name = responseEntry.get("1.0",END) # Get string of our name
    conclusionText.delete("1.0", END)   # delete the text in our conclusion text widget
    conclusionText.insert(END, "Ah, so your name is " + name[:-1] + "?") # Update text in conclusion text widget. NOTE: name ends with a new line

responseEntry.bind('<KeyRelease>', typing) # bind responseEntry to keyboard keys being released, and have it execute the function typing when this occurs

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.